# flutter app error: Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app' of type org.gra

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, gradle

This is the whole error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\app_project\rop_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 3
- What went wrong:
  An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0.0']

> Failed to apply plugin 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

Here is my android\build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is my android\app\build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id "com.android.application"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.firebase.rop_app"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.firebase.rop_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

here is my settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
        id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.0" apply false
    }
}

include ":app"

apply from: "${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

any help would be appreciated :)

i have seen similar problem here tried moving some line but it didnt work